# logging rollover does not follow TimeBasedRollingPolicy in creation of archive files

Tags: xml, spring, logging, logback

I have a logback-spring.xml that uses daily rollover implementation of TimeBasedRollingPolicy.
The only time it creates the archive file is after a successful rebuild of the microservice.

I was expecting I would be having the same number of archived log files depending on the number of successful calls of the microservice given that the calls were an interval of more than a minute or so.

It does not also log the LOG.info and LOG.error methods I placed within my classes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<configuration>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
<appender name="DAILY" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>/var/log/logs/myLog.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">

        <!-- minute rollover, for testing only -->
        <fileNamePattern>/var/log/archive/myLog.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.log</fileNamePattern>  

    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="DAILY" />
</root>  
</configuration>
```

any idea where I got something wrong in my configuration?

Comment: are you sure your logback xml is getting picked up?

Comment: yes, both log file and archived file are getting created